# Wordpress corrupted by plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

after I installed this plugin

https://www.jojo-themes.net/jc-woocommerce-advanced-product-attributes-v1-3-0/

some crucial plugins disappeared from backoffice, including one mentioned above. If I try to install them again, errors are thrown by all plugins, for example:

> An error occurred while installing Revolution Slider: Folder already exists.

I have tried to remove problematic plugin by removing its folder, but with no luck.

I am using Wordpress 5.0.3 with Woocommerce.

Website address is https://nove.vozikyprozivot.cz

Can anyone please tell me what to do?

Thank you very much for any clues.

Eduard

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution: I have renamed problematic plugin folder, then installed it again from administration, deactivated an removed. Then I renamed every plugin folder which was missing and installed again. No data missing, everything is working now.

I think that plugin is not compatible with my wordpress version and did some changes in database.

Comment: Yes, some plugins are like that.